# Update symfony form using two routes in a controller

Tags: symfony, controller, symfony-forms

I am having problems updating a form using two routes. I have a monaco editor (code editor package from microsoft) which can contain json data. On clicking a button, fields shall be generated in form of a bootstrap accordion. This is most likely handled by easyadmin a library with forms from symfony. The purpose of all of this is that there's a json editor, below there are fieldDefinitions in form of an accordion tree view which can be generated by the jsonData. The json data is being converted into a custom json with php annotation types. And then there's also a twig-editor in a twig template which wraps this one and another monaco editor, and the twig-editor shall render a pdf preview using mPDF library. this is the code from my twig template:

```
{% block main %}
    <div class="editor-wrapper" id="json-editor-wrapper">
        <div class="editor" id="json-editor"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-secondary btn" id="apply-button" onclick="applyFields();">⬆️ Felder zu Config ⬇️</button>
    <div class="field-definitions-wrapper">
        {{ form(fieldDefinitionsForm) }}
    </div>

    <script>
        function applyFields() {
            let jsonData;
            const monacoScript = document.createElement('script');
            monacoScript.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js';
            monacoScript.async = true;
            monacoScript.onload = function() {
                require.config({ paths: { vs: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor/min/vs' } });
                require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
                    jsonData = monaco.editor.getEditors()[0].getValue();

                    fetch('/updateFields', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({ fields: jsonData }),
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log(data.fieldData);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error updating fields: ', error);
                    });
                });
            };
            document.head.appendChild(monacoScript);
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And here's the corresponding controllers code:

```
class TwigToPdfController extends AbstractController
{
    use WithTwigEnvironmentTrait;
    use UseTokenizedConfigurationTrait;

    public const ROUTE_PANEL_ITEM = 'twigToPdf';
    public LoggerInterface $logger;
    private MessageStructureDefinition $msd;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->msd = new MessageStructureDefinition();
    }

    #[Route('/renderPdf', name: self::ROUTE_PANEL_ITEM)]
    // Initial render of pdf on loading the page.
    public function renderPdf(Request $request): Response
    {
        $fieldDefinitions = $this->render('field_definitions/field_definitions.html.twig', [
            'fieldDefinitionsForm' => $this->createForm(FieldDefinitionsFormType::class, $this->msd)->createView()
        ]);

        $twigTemplate = $this->twig->createTemplate(""); // Empty twig template string
        $renderedTemplate = $twigTemplate->render([]); // Resolve twig template to pure html

        $mpdf = new Mpdf();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($renderedTemplate);
        $pdf = $mpdf->Output('', dest: Destination::STRING_RETURN);
        $pdfDataUrl = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' . base64_encode($pdf);
        $pdfPreview = $this->renderView('pdfpreview/pdfpreview.html.twig', [
            'preview' => $pdfDataUrl
        ]);

        // Render the parent template and include child templates as variables
        return $this->render('twig_to_pdf/twigToPdf.html.twig', [
            'fieldDefinitions' => $fieldDefinitions,
            'pdfPreview' => $pdfPreview
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/updateFields')]
    public function updateFields(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        // Decode the JSON data into a PHP array
        $requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        if ($requestData === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            // Handle JSON decoding errors
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Invalid JSON data'], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // Access the "fields" key to get the JSON data
        $fieldData = json_decode($requestData['fields'], true);

        return new JsonResponse([
            'fieldData' => $fieldData
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/updatePdf')]
    // Updates pdf by filling it with header, body/content & footer.
    public function updatePdf(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $requestData = json_decode($request->getContent() ?? '{}'); // Parse JSON data

        /*
         * Generate PDF using mPDF based on $headerContent, $bodyContent, $footerContent.
         * Those need to be the final html which results of the resolved twig data.
         */
        $mpdf = new Mpdf();
        $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($this->twig->createTemplate($requestData->header)->render((array)$requestData->twigParams));
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($this->twig->createTemplate($requestData->body)->render((array)$requestData->twigParams));
        $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($this->twig->createTemplate($requestData->footer)->render((array)$requestData->twigParams));

        try {
            // Output the PDF as a string
            $pdfData = $mpdf->Output('', 'S'); // 'S' option generates the PDF as a string

            // Return the PDF data as JSON
            return new JsonResponse([
                'pdfData' => base64_encode($pdfData)
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle PDF generation error
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'PDF generation failed'], Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ChatGPT is very much frowned upon on this site.  Might consider editing your question to actually include a question.

Comment: Just that I wrote that on my own and didn't use AI for it, but aight.

Comment: Well okay.  The title talks about two routes.  The words indicate a custom js editor.  Your controller code shows two actions one returning json and one returning a pdf string inside of json.   Your js code seems to setup a call to updateFields but I don't see anything about updatePdf.  But nothing to indicate what the problem is. Or does everything work and this is just a "for info" question?